# Crear PopUp o Modal que permita crear Formulario

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, modal, popup

Es mejor si añado mas detalle de como está el código.

TextBox (cabe resaltar que tengo 31 de estos)

```
<td>
<asp:TextBox class="form-control" ID="TextBox11" runat="server" style="padding: 0px 0px;width: 36px; font-size: 11.5px;" ReadOnly OnTextChanged="TextBox11_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Ahora bien, con respecto al Panel y ModalPopUp

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableCDN="true" runat="server"> 
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnableCDN="true" runat="server"> 
</asp:ScriptManager>

<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" CancelControlID="btnthree" OkControlID="btntwo" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="backgroundColor"> 
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalpopup">
  <asp:Label ID="Labeltwo" runat="server" Text="Detalle"></asp:Label>
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListone" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>FER</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>JESUS</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>JAVI</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
  <asp:Button ID="btntwo" runat="server" Text="ENVIAR" UseSubmitBehavior="False" OnClick="btntwo_Click" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnthree" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
 </asp:Panel>
```

Por el lado interno tengo lo siguiente, así para cada textbox

```
protected void TextBox11_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
}
```

Comment: Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ¿Como crear un modal con un formulario dentro? Tal como se detalla en la segunda imagen.

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta ahora? y el modal que tiene que ver con el backend o con sql-server?

Comment: Realicé un modal con JavaScript, pero no pude hacer que al hacer click en el textBox  me abra el modal. Con respecto al backend quiero saber la funcionalidad que se tiene que hacer para poder interactuar con los datos para poder registrar en mi base de datos que se encuentra en Sql-Server

Comment: Tu pregunta es como demasiado amplia. Lo del backend no se si es posible contestartelo. No dices nada de como es o que tenes. Lo del modal probaste algo? un evento click en un textbox? o que sean botones que parezcan textbox y usar su evento click?

Comment: Buena idea lo del evento click en Texbox: data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" .... Logré que funcione con eso. ¿Podrías darme una idea de como logro pasar de una tabla a otra los registros que considero pertinentes como lo puse en la segunda imagen de arriba?

Answer (score 1):

Si es asp.net recomiendo que hagas el popup utilizando el `Modal Popup Extender` del `ajax tookit`

En el articulo lo explico

[[ASP.NET] PopUp Edición - Usando Ajax Toolkit ModalPopupExtender](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2012/06/aspnet-popup-edicion-usando-ajax.html)

En el codigo observaras el uso del

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeEditOrder" runat="server" 
    PopupControlID="panelEditOrder" TargetControlID="HiddenField1"
     BackgroundCssClass="backgroundColor" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="panelEditOrder" runat="server" BackColor="White">

     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEditOrder" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>  

              .
              .
              .
          </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Asi defines el `Panel` del `popup` que obtendra los datos cuando se presione el boton de edicion del grid

```
    protected void gvOrders_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        int OrderId = Convert.ToInt32(gvOrders.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value);

        InitializeEditPopUp();
        LoadEditData(OrderId);

        mpeEditOrder.Show();
    }
```

con el `mpeEditOrder.Show();` mostrar el dialog habiendo previamente cargado los datos en los controles

Comment: Hola Leandro, logré crear el modal Ajax y funciona cuando hago click en el textbox mediante TargetControlID="TextBox11" . Tengo 31 <asp:textbox>, cada uno con id diferente. mi duda surge como lograr que al hacer click en cualquier textbox, se abra el modal.

Comment: si analizas el articulo veras que alli asigno el TargetControlID a un Hidden, de esta forma el Show() lo realizo desde codigo, en tu caso lo harias en los eventos de estos textbox

Comment: Asigné un TargetControlID="HiddenField1" a mi ModalPopupExtender1, despues para cada `textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){ModalPopupExtender1.Show();}` pero no me funciona, alguna sugerencia de que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: revisaste sino hay un error de javascript, desde al consola del developer tools? tenes asignada la propiedad AutoPostback en true para los textbox

Comment: Edité mi pregunta Leandro, ahí muestro el código que estoy siguiendo

Comment: @FernandoSalinas el evento TextChanged se produce cuando ingresas un valor en el textbox, como puedes hacer esto si has puesto `ReadOnly`. Intenta poner otor evento como el click de un boton para validar que funcione el popup